# IntelliJ IDEA empty constructor/method code style

Tags: intellij-idea

How to tweak InlliJ IDEA 14 code style for Java, to make it keep closing brace of empty constructor/method right after opening one.

E. g. :

```java
class A {
    private A() {}
    public void b() {}
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Code style/Java/Wrapping and Braces* and select these options:

- Keep when reformatting

  - Simple blocks in one line
  - Simple methods in one line
  - Simple classes in one line

That will keep code like this untouched while reformatting your code:

```
if(true) {}
public void foo() {}
public class Bar {}
```

I tested this on IntelliJ 13.1.5, but hopefully it will work the same way on 14 too.

Comment: Too bad this applies to both empty blocks and blocks consisting of only one line. I'd like to keep empty blocks on a single line but wrap all other kind of blocks. Not possible?

Comment: For java 8 there is a new option: `Simple lambdas in one line`

Comment: @DidierL in 2021.1.1, how it works is that if the empty block or the block with a single statement was written on one line, the formatter formats it as a one-liner; if some manual typing put the closing brace and/or the single statement on a new line, it will be formatted as a 2-liner (empty block) or 3-liner (single statement block). So, some manual formatting is needed to direct the formatter. (Yeah, I know this is 6 years late. Up to now have been using Eclipse and then the strict Google Java Formatter.)

Comment: Bohuslav's example does not include a "simple" constructor, which the original question includes. I find that simple constructors still get split with the above config, which is unlike the google java formatter plugin

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the default behaviour of IntelliJ 14? At least in my version it is. As soon as I open curly bracket it gets closed automatically on the same line.

Comment: Afrer applying «Reformat code…», brace moves to the next line.

Comment: Preferences -> Code Style -> Java - take a look there if you haven't but I doubt that there will be an option after reformat...

Comment: I haven't found there any corresponding option, that is why I am here on StackOverflow.